# Split String and store it into a List in C#

Tags: c#, string, list, split

I have a situation where I have to go to specific index position "20" in a string and then find the last index of '|' and split string from there. Now I have to repeat the same process on the remaining string and store it in a list. I need a code which can handle any size of string. Below code is just to explain what I need.

For example:

```
        string testData = "(Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test)";
        string str = testData.Substring(0, 20);
        int index = str.LastIndexOf('|') + 1;
        string x = testData.Substring(0, index), y = testData.Substring(index);

        string str2 = y.Substring(0, 20);
        int index2 = str2.LastIndexOf('|') + 1;
        string x2 = y.Substring(0, index2), y2 = y.Substring(index2);

        string str3 = y2.Substring(0, 20);
        int index3 = str3.LastIndexOf('|') + 1;
        string x3 = y2.Substring(0, index3), y3 = y2.Substring(index3);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x2);
        Console.WriteLine(x3);
        Console.WriteLine(y3);
```

Output is:

```
(Test) | (Test) | <br>
(Test) | (Test) | <br>
(Test) | (Test) | <br>
(Test)
```

I need to store this output in a list.
Please help.

Comment: [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0).

Comment: And then [ToList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Why are you doing `LastIndexOf('&')`? There isn't a single **`&`** present in your string.

Comment: It's my bad. I should have replaced "&" by "|"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this solution:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string veryLongText = @"(Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test) | (Test)";

        var result = SplitString(veryLongText, 20);
        if (result != null)
            foreach (var t in result)
                Console.WriteLine($"{t.Length,3} : '{t}'");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<string> SplitString(string data, int length)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        if (data.Split(' ').Any(x => x.Length > length))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR, SINGLE WORD EXCEED THE CURRENT LIMIT!");
            return null;
        }

        int lastSpace = 0;
        int currentSpace = 0;
        int newLinePos = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data.Length - newLinePos <= length)
            {
                result.Add(data.Substring(newLinePos, data.Length - newLinePos));
                break;
            }
            if (data[i] == '|')
            {
                lastSpace = currentSpace;
                currentSpace = i;
                if (currentSpace - newLinePos > length)
                {
                    result.Add(data.Substring(newLinePos, lastSpace - newLinePos));
                    newLinePos = lastSpace + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is good but it returned only 2 strings instead of 4. But now I have the idea how to solve my problem. Thanks for your help!